A closed ideal of a closed ideal of a unital commutative $C^*-$algebra is also a closed ideal.
Let $A$ be a unital commutative $C^*$-algebra. If $B$ is a closed ideal of $A$, and $C$ is a closed ideal of $B$, prove that $C$ is a closed ideal of $A$.

What have you tried?

@EvangelopoulosFoivos It is possible to use the Gelfand transformation, but I do not have any idea how to proceed.

Neither unitality nor commutativity is needed for this. Indeed, if $C$ is a closed ideal in $B$, which is in turn a closed ideal in $A$, then clearly $C$ is closed in $A$. To prove it is an ideal, let $c \in C_+$ and $a \in A$. Since $c^{1/2} \in C \subset B$ and $B$ is an ideal of $A$, we have $ac^{1/2} \in B$. Then as $C$ is an ideal of $B$, we have $ac = (ac^{1/2})c^{1/2} \in C$. Positive elements span $C$, so $ac \in C$ for all $a \in A$ and $c \in C$. Similarly, one can show that $ca \in C$ for all $a \in A$ and $c \in C$ as well.

Nice answer! Thank you!
